# Android Studio - Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, sdk

so I updated my Android Studio yesterday, since then I get an error when I try to build the project, gradle output is this:

**Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0**

Double-clicking the error brings me to the build.gradle file (app module)
here is a screenshot of the file:
[image]

I tried downloading and using Sdk version 7, api lvl 24, but it would not help. Also I don't know what version to type for the highlighted lines when I use a higher idk version.

Sorry if it is a stupid question. Other questions relating the same could not give me a solution. It always says to update the jdk, but this was tried by me when using Sdk 7 in the sdk manager or no?

**update**
I now also updated the JRE to java 8 and still get the same problem.
Furthermore I recognized this warning:
[image]

which says I use idk 26 build tools Oo
removing the recommended line does not solve the above error
I am so confused

Comment: you are running your code on a version of JRE that is older compared to the version of the JDK you compiled with

Comment: as far as I know I only updated android studio, and did not change the sdk version. Maybe android studio did this by itself?

Comment: Try to invalidate cache/restart, then clean and rebuild project. Are you getting the same error when you create new, blank project?

Comment: invalidating cache and reset unfortunately did not solve it.
Creating a blank project gives a new error:
-----
Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: /Users/yesyor/Library/Android/sdk  Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) Install missing platform(s) and sync project-----
the problem must be there, this android 26 Sdk also appears as a warning as shown above in my project

Comment: What version of gradle plugin?

Comment: where do I find it? :)
oh god why does updating the android studio always messes around with gradle and Sdk settings :D

Comment: In project build.gradle

Comment: grade version 4.1
android plugin version 3.0.1

Comment: error solved: in the project structure, sdk location it demanded a jdk 8. telling it to used the embedded jdk solved the problem.